# I ate a gelatin product with uncertainty now I'm unsure about what to do

Tags: halal-haram, allah

Please help and assist me because I have accidently eaten gelatin in my ice cube gum candy. Well actully here's what happened...

So a couple of months ago, my brother had brought an ice cube breakers gum candy and me and my freinds loved to eat gum in school so I decided to take it and share with them everyday because I wanted to be nice. I offered it to 4 of my freinds and 3 of them took and said thank you but one of them had warned me something I never forgot. She told me she didn't want it because this type of gum had gelatin inside... I honestly had a bad feeling about this but scince I wasn't for sure and my dad and brother was ok with buying this then I just decided to go along with it and I can't remember exactly why I never checked the ingredients on the back but I'm thinking it's because I was too scared that she would actually be right and I would see gelatin on the back and feel guilty for not listening. So I had assumed I would rather not know than me knowing and then feeling guilty on not listening to her. Now it was a couple of months later and I was researching if Oreo cookies were halal to eat and I had randomly gotten the memory of the gum and her telling me about it, so I decided to check for myself and search it up. Then to my horror it actually did say gelatin and now I am unsure on what to do because I not only ate myself, but I also shared with my freinds and why would I do such a horrible thing when I could have just red the ingredients on the back sooner. Now I have already made a Dua apologizing to Allah (SWT) for my evil deed but I wish to feel more sincere about it and I wish for any of you to help me and give me some Dua or repentance suggestions to gain complete forgiveness from Allah (SWT). Any help would be appreciated and may Allah (SWT) bless you all Ameen

Answer (score 0):

I'm an Islamic religion teacher and BA holder in Islamic jurisprudents I say:

not all sins a have a specialized or ritualistic way of repentance
the only way to repent just ask Allah for forgiveness and don't repeat you're actions
keep saying "استغفر الله"
always remember that Allah is the most merciful and don't lose hope of his forgiveness
as god said in the surah of الزمر

" قُلْ يَا عِبَادِيَ الَّذِينَ أَسْرَفُوا عَلَىٰ أَنفُسِهِمْ لَا تَقْنَطُوا مِن رَّحْمَةِ اللَّهِ ۚ إِنَّ اللَّهَ يَغْفِرُ الذُّنُوبَ جَمِيعًا ۚ إِنَّهُ هُوَ الْغَفُورُ الرَّحِيمُ "

“Say, ‘O My servants who have transgressed against themselves, do not despair of God’s mercy. Indeed, God forgives all sins. Indeed, He is the Forgiving, the Merciful.’”

may Allah bless you and forgave us all